# How to create a Generic list parameter which will accept all the type of classes?

Tags: c#-4.0, generic-list

```
public void GenerateExcelReport(List<EventHistory> lstData)
    {
    }
```

I am using the above list as Parameter (i.e. the list of type "EventHistory" class) if I want to pass all types of lists, then how to create the list parameter generally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the generic type parameter for T to your method:

```
 void GenerateExcelReport<T>(List<T> list){
 }
```

Then call it:

```
    GenerateExcelReport(stringList);
    GenerateExcelReport(objectList);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to process all kind of lists, the only thing that is generic is the `t` in   the `List<T>`:

```
public void GenerateExcelReport<T>(List<T> lstData)
{
    // ...
}
```

Documentation: [Generic Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx)

Since you've mentioned that you want to "accept all the type of classes?", you could add a constraint to allow only classes and not value types:

```
public void GenerateExcelReport<T>(List<T> lstData) where T: class
{}
```